# scapy sr function problems

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, scapy

I'm having trouble receiving all related packets to a request when using scapy's sr function.

```
ans, unans = sr(IP(dst="172.xxx.xxx.xxx")/TCP(dport=80,flags="S"))
```

returns:

```
Received 2 packets, got 1 answers, remaining 0 packets
```

What happens is that I first get an ICMP redirect. Afterwards I get the answer from my local service with SA. Sometimes it tells me it received two packets, which makes sense, but when I look at it in the summary it prints the following:

```
<bound method SndRcvList.summary of <Results: TCP:0 UDP:0 ICMP:1 Other:0>>
```

and in summary() I find this:

```
IP / TCP 172.xxx.xxx.xxx:ftp_data > 172.zzz.zzz.zzz:http S ==> IP / ICMP 172.yyy.yyy.yyy > 172.xxx.xxx.xxx redirect host-redirect / IPerror / TCPerror
```

For one, I wonder where my SA flagged TCP packet is. When I look at the network dump, I definitely see it, right after the ICMP packet. I've made sure to run scapy with and without running tcpdump, just in case it would interfere, which it shouldn't.

I've also tried to set and increased timeout, just in case it didn't wait long enough to receive the TCP packet. Didn't work.

I've also tried it out on loopback interface, the local lan and systems that are located in the internet. Same result everywhere.

Any ideas on where the error could be located?

Comment: I've found https://github.com/phaethon/scapy/commit/d5f6219c4cb70eb27c10a1989b72541ae2341585 - but a direct backport doesn't fix it. And somehow python3 with scapy for python3 port doesn't run: `>>> from scapy.all import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
[...]
    from .fields import StrField,ConditionalField,Emph,PacketListField
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/scapy/fields.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .volatile import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/scapy/volatile.py", line 609
    rb"C:\CON\CON",
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Ok, it doesn't seem that that issue was relevant to my problem. The import error is fixed in the meantime. Was a version conflict from python version 3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scapy considers this ICMP packet to be response on initial TCP SYN request (which it actually is). Try using `sr(..., multi = True)` to get multiple response packets.